# «Вытемниться» — есть такое слово?

Tags: лексика, словообразование, окказионализмы

Возможно ли такое словообразование? Например в контексте, что силуэты вытемнились на фоне яркого света (то есть стали тёмными, чёрными).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, в русской литературе подобные окказионализмы (или как уж их там назвать) - дело привычное. Но вот вне художественного текста да без объяснений скорее всего не поймут. У меня возникает ощущение, что речь может идти о каком-то постепенном процессе... Вот встаёт солнце - и происходит это самое "вытемнение". В динамике, а не просто на фоне... Так что очень может быть, что просто не поймут.

Смотрите, насколько вам это слово важно и насколько понятно по контексту.

Answer (score 4):

Здесь авторское словообразование (по случаю, для местной выразительности -  в соответствии с худож. задачами автора) поясняется контекстным оформлением: нечто *выделилось* своими тёмными очертаниями на фоне подсветки. Речь о выделении, поскольку слово образовано по аналогии с существующим словом "**высветляться**" (становиться светлым в результате освещения, обнаруживаться, делаться явным - слов. Ефремовой). Однако вне контекста такое слово противоречит смыслу "*выявления*", поскольку однокоренные слова (темнить, затемнять, темное /дело/) традиционно имеют противоположную направленность (скрыть - в прямом или переносном смысле). Поэтому само по себе такое слово могло бы выражать только противоположность слову "высветляться", но для этого в нём приставка не слишком подходящая (она как в слове "**вы**деляться" - становиться заметным на фоне чего-л.); возможно, поэтому слово с противоположным смыслом (включая переносный - становиться неясным и пр.) закрепилось в виде "***за***темнять(ся)", а "вытемняться" не нашло применения.

Comment: _Третьему глазу_ спасибо за вопрос; Вам, _Alex_ander_, — за ответ! В поддержку: _Все еще день жил в их переулочке, все еще зной держался. А уже был вечер. И **вытемнилось** за домами небо_ (Лазарь Карелин. Последний переулок).

Answer (score 2):

Словарями не фиксируется, но мало ли чего ими не фиксируется. Глагол "вытемнить" образован с соблюдением всех правил словообразования (у Чуковского в "От двух до пяти": вот уточка притонула, а вот вытонула, - и автор аплодирует).

Используйте на здоровье, если из контекста всё ясно.

Народ, кстати, обходится без штампа "Уплочено":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И даже [в стихи](http://magazines.russ.ru/ra/2013/7/13ts.html) попало:

> Мы опускались
>
> все глубже в бездну Маккии, и ты
>
> наконец подполз ближе.
>
> Но мы не смогли
>
> что-либо тебе вытемнить:
>
> нами правила
>
> неизбежность света.

Или:

> Вытемнить небо, высыпать звёздами,
>
> Выстудить утро речами морозными.
>
> Иглистой льдинкой ткнуться в ладошку,
>
> Принять тепло, умереть понарошку...

Comment: В ваших же примерах - **с другим значением**.

Comment: *Народ, кстати, обходится без штампа "Уплочено":* - а это к чему? Ну то, что делать скрин с яндекса - неуважительно к читающему и ресурсу, повторять уже устал... Вот как я теперь Ваши откровения процитирую?  Руками набирать?